# A question about bracketing in generalized associative law for groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have started studying dummit foote, and there  is proposition,

If $G$ is a group under the operation $*$ For any $a_1,a_2,...,a_n \in G$ the value of $a_1∗a_2∗...∗a_n$ is independent of how the expression is bracketed(this is called the generalized associative law).

And in the sketch of the proof they have written

Next assume for any $k \lt n$ that any bracketing of a product of $k$ elements $b_1*b_2*\ldots*b_k$ can be reduced(without altering the value of the product) to an expression of the form $$b_1 * (b_2 * (b_3 * (\ldots * b_k)) \ldots )$$

Now I want to understand how it is really bracketing. I want to know what is in the
$(\ldots * b_k)$.For instance if I write full expression,is it like this $$b_1 * (b_2 * (b_3 * (\ldots (b_{k-1} * b_k)) \ldots )$$ .   For example for $n=7$ this expression $b_1 * (b_2 * (b_3 * (\ldots * b_k)) \ldots )$ reduced to $b_1*(b_2*(b_3*(...*b_7))...)$ and unbinding this
we have this backing $b_1*(b_2*(b_3*(b_4*(b_5(b_6*b7)))))$. Is it right? Or is it reduced any other form. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Yes you understand the notation correctly.

Comment: @leon.fuchsler okay thanks for clarifying

Comment: The use of $\ldots$ is always hiding an induction. Here the slightly more rigorous inductive definition would be $a_i = b_{k-i} * a_{i-1}$ for $i>0$ with $a_0 = b_k$. Then $a_{k-1}$ is your $b_1 * (b_2 * ( \ldots (b_{k-1} * b_k )) \ldots )$.

Comment: Would it be easier to read if it were written in a way so that the open parenthesis match to the close parenthesis?  $b_1*\underbrace{(b_2*\underbrace{(b_3*\underbrace{(b_4*\underbrace{(...*(b_{k-1}*b_k)  ...)})})})}$.  This isn't meant to be deep or profound; it's just all the levels of interation are alluded to by $...$ but as we have to both open and close parenthesis we have to do it in two places.  And.... I agree with you.  I *does* look weird and easy to get lost in.  But it is what you think (although BTW $b_1 * (b_2 * (b_3 * (\ldots (b_{k-1} * b_k)) \ldots )$ has 4 open but 3 close.)

Comment: @fleablood yeah there will be one more bracket at end, then it will be 4 open 4 close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right.

I wouldn't try to evaluate parts of it, such as looking at the value of $(\ldots * b_k)$, but instead consider it a string of symbols. There are two repeating patterns, on either side of $b_k$:
$$\underbrace{\underbrace{b_1 \, * \, (}\, \underbrace{b_2 \, * \, (} \, \underbrace{b_3 \, * \, (} \ldots \underbrace{b_{k-1} \, * \, (}}_{\text{A pattern of $k-1$ "blocks"}} \, b_k \, \underbrace{)))\ldots)}_{\text{$k - 1$ times}}$$
Note, in my formulation, I included some extra superfluous parentheses around $b_k$, just to emphasise the pattern. But, other than these extra parentheses, I am saying the same thing as Dummitt and Foote.

Comment: Then according to this repeating pattern for $n=7$ we have $a_1*(a_2*(a_3*(a_4*(a5*(a_6*(a_7))))))$,  but I have written above $a_1*(a_2*(a_3*(a_4*(a5*(a_6*a_7)))))$. Is this two equivalent? Well I know this two equivalent,  as this is what gernalized associative law says, but I am asking in terms bracketing. Thanks for your excellent answer

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned, the extra parentheses are the only difference between what I was intending and what D&F are intending. Yes, these are equivalent. In terms of bracketing, the extra parentheses are superfluous, as they don't enclose any operations. The entire purpose of parentheses is to indicate which operations to perform first, and there are no operations inside $(a_7)$.

Comment: Hmmm..... Even if $*$ is not associative, if we have only one term the $b_1 = (b_1) = ((b_1)) = (((b_1)))$ etc.  Therefore if you have two terms $b_1*(b_2) = b_1*b_2 = (b_1)*b_2$.  There is nothing profound about this.